# Traveling from Gdansk Poland to UK London

Tags: poland, customs-and-immigration

I am traveling from the USA to Poland for a family gathering. I wanted to go to London while I am in Europe. While I was completing the purchase of airline tickets from Gdansk to London and London to Gdansk it asked in the declarations page:

> “I and all passengers on this booking are RESIDENT in Poland and we
>   are currently based in Poland”

Didn't understand this verbiage to be honest. So bottom line will I have issues getting on this flight and back to Poland with a USA passport?

Comment: That's a weird question. What airline is that, and on what site did you book? What this at the time of API (when they ask for your passport number etc.) or at some other point in the process?

Comment: It looks like something they would have you declare for a travel insurance, not for a ticket.

Comment: Could be special resident fares on LOT.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the Wizz Air site to test this, and Willeke's comment is spot on: the declaration about being resident in Poland only shows up if you select the optional Travel Insurance. If you are not resident in Poland, you should select "No Insurance" as you are not eligible for the Travel Insurance they are offering.  When you select "No Insurance", Wizz Air won't require any declaration about being resident in Poland.

If you already bought the tickets with the insurance, I think you don't need to worry about it. Since the declaration was only for the insurance anyway, I believe it won't cause you any problem for boarding the flight, and certainly not for passport control.  I believe it will only potentially cause the insurance to be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct - the question about residence is merely for insurance, as the insurance cost has likely been calculated on the risk basis of Polish residents travelling from Poland, rather than (the many other) possibilities.

With regards to flying from Poland to the UK and back again, you'll have no problem in either country using a US passport. Although I'm a dual national (UK/USA) now, I used to travel frequently (5+ times per year) between London and Gdansk.